# What is the difference between software.amazon.kinesis and com.amazonaws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to create an application to read from a Kinesis data stream.
MVN repository contains **software.amazon.kinesis:amazon-kinesis.client** and **com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client**.

What is the difference between these artifacts?
Which one should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

software.amazon.kinesis:amazon-kinesis.client (artifactId : amazon-kinesis-client)  is API version 2 and latest of Kinesis by AWS 
other one is V1